Completable Future with Executor for handling Exceptions only
There is a list of objects List<Foo> fooDetails, which I will use to create Bar request corresponding to each element of fooDetails from database and then do a rest template call.
public void startProcess(List<Foo> fooDetails) throws Exception {

List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = fooDetails.stream()
                .map(this::processFoo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> failedFooPushList = futures.stream()
                .map(future -> {
                    try {
                        return future.get();  // Returns null if successful for that store
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)  // Filter failed (non-null) results
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (!failedFooPushList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new SyncException("Foo failed for foo details: {}" + failedFooPushList);
        }
    }

    private CompletableFuture<String> processFoo(Foo fooDetail) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Bar request = barService.createBarFromDB(
                        Collections.singletonList(foodetail));

                boolean barPushFailed = booleanResponseClient.updateBar(request);

                if (barPushFailed) {
                    return fooDetail.getName();
                }

                return null;  // Return null to indicate success
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return fooDetail.getName();
            }
        });
    }

The list can be very large and I suppose I should use ExecutorService with it. I am new to Java and need to know How to get the list of all the names of from the List<Foo> fooDetails which threw exception in a thread-safe manner?

What makes you think this isn't thread safe?

You're already using an Executor, just one you're not seeing. CompletableFuture.supplyAsync will use some internal Executor if you don't pass an explicit one.

@RobSpoor Specifically, supplyAsync(Supplier) is documented to use the common ForkJoinPool.
